# How to write code like this picture?

Tags: math-mode, diagrams

[image]

And write macro books mathematics for publishing

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer!

Answer (score 6):

Welcome! With the `tikzmark` library it is straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
bla bla\vskip 2.8em
\[\tikzset{pft/.style={cyan,draw,inner sep=2pt}}
\tikzmarknode[pft]{l1}{-2A}\,x^2
-\tikzmarknode[pft]{l2}{8A-2B}\,x
+\tikzmarknode[pft]{l3}{2A-4B+2C}=
\tikzmarknode[cyan]{r1}{2}x^2-\tikzmarknode[cyan]{r2}{3}x
+\tikzmarknode[cyan]{r3}{6}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,cyan,-latex]
 \draw (l1.north) -- ++ (0,2em) -| node[pos=0.25,above] {equal} (r1);
 \draw (l2.north) -- ++ (0,1.5em) -| (r2);
 \draw (l3.north) --  ++ (0,1em) -| (r3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future I'd kindly like to ask you to post some code that you have tried. This spares others from typing in the equations from screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for share!!